# My sprite instances are not being displayed properly

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to implement a design where the brick columns are on the left and right sides of the action screen and a data/score screen is on the top. The brick class draws a rect sprite that has the proper size to fill the brick column space. I've made 2 instances for the two sides, but only the left-sided instance is showing and it's being drawn halfway lower than where I want it to be, and if I print the coordinates of the rect instances they are in the right place. Could anyone help me understand what I'm missing/doing wrong? Thank you in advance for your help!

settings.py (control panel class for the game)

```
class Settings():
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.BLACK = (0,0,0)
        self.GREEN = (0,255,0)
        # Game Screen
        self.screen_h = 600
        self.screen_w= int(self.screen_h * .6)
        self.size = (self.screen_w, self.screen_h)
        
        
        #Game layout--------------------

        # DataScreen specs
        self.data_h= int(self.screen_h/4)
        self.data_w= self.screen_w
        self.data_color = (255,255,0)# yellow
        
        # ActionScreen specs------------
        self.action_h = self.screen_h
        self.action_w = self.screen_w * .85
        
        self.action_x = int(self.screen_w * .15)
        self.action_y = self.data_h
       
        self.action_color = (173,216,230)# light blue

        # brick specs--------------

        self.brick_fill_h = int(self.screen_h - self.data_h)
        self.brick_fill_w = int(self.action_x)

        self.brick_inside_color =(252, 106, 3) # Tiger Orange
```

game_layout.py (display sprite classes file)

```
import pygame as pg
from settings import Settings

from pygame.sprite import Group,Sprite

BLACK=(0,0,0)

class DataScreen():
    def __init__(self,ai_set):
        self.width = ai_set.data_w
        self.height = ai_set.data_h
        self.image = pg.Surface([self.width,self.height])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        pg.draw.rect(self.image, ai_set.data_color, [0,0, self.width,self.height],5)

class ActionScreen():
    def __init__(self,ai_set):
        self.width = ai_set.action_w
        self.height = ai_set.action_h
        self.x = ai_set.action_x
        self.y = ai_set.action_y
        self.image = pg.Surface([self.width,self.height])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        pg.draw.rect(self.image, ai_set.action_color, [self.x,self.y, self.width,self.height])

class Brick(Sprite):
    def __init__(self,ai_set,x,y):
        super().__init__()
        self.width= ai_set.brick_fill_w
        self.height= ai_set.brick_fill_h #int(ai_set.screen_h)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = pg.Surface([self.width,self.height])
        self.image.set_colorkey(ai_set.BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x,y))
        pg.draw.rect(self.image,ai_set.brick_inside_color, [x,y,self.width,self.height])
```

game_fxn.py(functions necessary to run the game)

```
import pygame as pg
import sys
def check_events():
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                sys.exit()

def update(ai_set,screen,data_s,action_s,brick,brick2):#,bricks
    screen.fill(ai_set.BLACK)
    screen.blit(action_s.image, action_s.rect)
    screen.blit(data_s.image,data_s.rect)
    screen.blit(brick.image,brick.rect)
    screen.blit(brick2.image,brick2.rect)
    pg.display.update()
```

main.py (main game file)

```
import pygame as pg
import random
from settings import Settings
from platforms import Tile, Spike
from player import Player
from game_layout import DataScreen, ActionScreen, Brick
import game_fxn as gf
from pygame.sprite import Group

pg.init()

ai_set=Settings()
screen = pg.display.set_mode(ai_set.size)

pg.display.set_caption  = "Game 1"
data_s = DataScreen(ai_set)
action_s = ActionScreen(ai_set)

def main():
    brick = Brick(ai_set,0,ai_set.data_h)
    brick2 = Brick(ai_set,(ai_set.action_x+ai_set.action_w),ai_set.data_h-ai_set.data_h/2)
    while True:
        gf.check_events() 
        gf.update(ai_set,screen, data_s, action_s,brick,brick2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is what I'm getting:

[image: cool beans]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top left coordinates of `ActionScreen` and `Brick` are saved in the `x` and `y` attributes. However, when you draw something on the `image`, you must use coordinates relative to the *Surface*, but not relative to the screen. the top left coordinate of an *Surface* is always (0, 0):

```py
class ActionScreen():
    def __init__(self,ai_set):
        # [...]

        pg.draw.rect(self.image, ai_set.action_color, [0, 0, self.width, self.height])

class Brick(Sprite):
    def __init__(self,ai_set,x,y):
        # [...]

        pg.draw.rect(self.image,ai_set.brick_inside_color, [0, 0, self.width, self.height])
```

The coordinates of `brick2` are wrong:

```py
def main():
    brick = Brick(ai_set, 0, ai_set.data_h)
    brick2 = Brick(ai_set, ai_set.action_w, ai_set.data_h)
    while True:
        gf_check_events() 
        gf_update(ai_set,screen, data_s, action_s, brick, brick2)
```

Comment: I didn't add a top left attribute into the get_rect() method for the action screen but it still was positioned in the middle because I added the position into the pygame.draw.rect method . If I try the same approach for the brick class without the topleft attribute it doesn't work. I'm curious to know why that is.